# Injecting C# DLL into another application and displaying it

Tags: c#, forms, dll, code-injection

I have a C# browser app that I compiled as a DLL. I used forms and Visual Studio to make it. Would I be able to inject that DLL into an application and have that browser window displayed? Something similar to Steam's Shift+Tab overlay. I tried injecting it, but with no surprise it does not show up. If that's not possible, what's the best way to achieve what i'm looking for?

Comment: What do you mean compiled as a dll, a .net assembly, or a standard windows PE file ?

Comment: @TheGeneral , .NET framework 4.7.2, output type Class Library.

Comment: Just curious, what is your definition of DLL injection, and how are you injecting this

Comment: @TheGeneral , I use ExtremeInjector. From my understanding, if it's the same concept as with C++ injection, I will just run my code inside of another application. I want to have hotkey, for example, that will display or hide my browser gui on press.

Comment: Well, based on what it says on the website, yes, it should be possible, I guess you need to declare some method that this extreme injector was to call, and that method should wire some listener for e.g. keyboard input to launch that window, but that is not impossible.

Comment: I find it very unlikely that it is injecting a .net assembly into the process space of another application. Injection usually works by inserting a jmp command to point to your dll's method somewhere in its code. I could be wrong, but i know of no library that will do this for a .net assembly.

Comment: @TheGeneral https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023379/injecting-a-managed-dll-into-a-native-process has code, more can be found https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+injectt+dll. As far as I understand 4.x runtime allows running multiple version side by side even... so with some luck one can have multiple unrelated plugins running... Doable and I even used one hacked into an old MMO game ~15 years ago...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ahh ok, thanks,  i stand corrected.